# How can I set a maximum number of rows in an array Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a Google App Script that sends POST data contained within each row to an API Gateway URL. However, after the first 6 rows there is an issue and the POST data isn't getting processed properly, perhaps a stacking problem with Lambda.

How can I ensure only a maximum of 6 rows are used in an array script? Here is the code

```
// Work through each row in the spreadsheet
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];  
    // Assign each row a variable   
    var index = row[0];     // Col A: Index Sequence Number
    var img = row[1];   // Col B: Image Row
    var url = row[2];      // Col C: URL Row
    var emailStatus = row[lastColumn - 1];  // Col E: Email Status (has the email been forwarded/sent to the site owner)
```

Comment: Use two loops..

Comment: You mean that : `for (var i = 0; i < 6; ++i)` ?

Comment: Or better : `data=data.slice(0,6)` before the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i+=6) {
  vOut=[];
  for(var j=0;j<6;j++) {
    vOut.push(data[i+j];
  }
  //post vOut;
}
```